# What is the numerical value for "slow"?

Tags: jquery

If I were to do `.fadeIn('slow')`

what would be the number that replaces the word slow but is the same exact speed?

Comment: Why didn't you just look [at the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)?

Comment: Yeah go ahead and upvote this question, free reputation for all

Comment: jQuery provides documentation for its methods. If you have a question about one of the jQuery methods, check the documentation first.

Comment: Even a simple test would get you in the ballpark: `var n=Date.now(); $('div:first').hide().fadeIn('slow',function(){alert(Date.now()-n);});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L611):

```
slow: 600
```

And from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#duration):

> **Duration**
>   Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and
>   'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600
>   milliseconds, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

From jQuery documentation

> The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of
>   200 and 600

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `$.fx.speeds.slow`. By default it is `600` (600ms).

Answer (score 1):

```
.fadeIn(600);
```

which is 0.6 seconds

Answer (score 1):

> The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

"The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively." [.fadeIn() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)